# "Direct Messaging" Tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Could someone create a "Direct Messaging" tag? This would be different from "Private Messaging" (although there isn't one of these either.) There is very little documentation by Salesforce around [Direct Messaging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_direct_messages.htm&type=5), and it would be helpful to have a tag to draw questions on this functionality together.

Comment: Just create a question and than apply that tag. Anyone can create a new tag in this way. If no one has any questions about it, there is no need to create it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, creating the new tag requires at least 300 reputation, which I do not have at this time.

Comment: Do you have a specific post to which you would like it added?

Comment: Yes - [Allow Users to Leave (Exit) a Direct Message conversation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265701/allow-users-to-leave-exit-a-direct-message-conversation)